# How to give PAM authentificated users sudo powers?

Tags: ldap, sudo, pam

I set up PAM linked to an openldap, and I want all the authentificated users to be able to use sudo.

I thought I could create a posix group in the ldap called sudoersgroup, and write a rule in `/etc/sudoers` like:

```
 %sudoersgroup   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

but when I execute the "id" command, the membership does not appear, the only membership I have is the gidNumber one.

Did I miss something? Can I add them via pam_group? (I couldn't find how to correctly use this module)

Comment: Your idea for using groups to grant sudo access is essentially correct (although I question the wisdom of granting each and every user complete access). Maybe your pam ldap module still needs to be configured to actually look for and populate group maps. (in nsswitch.conf, and/or the ldap configuration settings)

Comment: As users can only be authentificated via LDAP, i set a filter si only admin member could authentificate, so nothing to worry about :)

i found this manpage : https://linux.die.net/man/5/group.conf 
that explains that in /etc/security/group.conf can grant group membership to logged in users with this syntax : services;ttys;users;times;groups.
So i think i can do xsh; tty* ;*;*;sudo.
But there is little documentation, so i'm no really sure if this is secure or no. :/